# Append a list as rows of empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add the rows from one data frame to another empty data frame;

```
for index, rows in data.iterrows():
    new = list(rows)
    var = new[0]

    for i in ran:
        if var in ran:
            empty_df.append(new)
```

I select a random first column entry such as 'image1.png' and then want to select all rows which have 'image1' in the first column. I then want to move those rows to a new data frame.

```
new = ['image1.png', 1023, 554, 1126, 646, 'nucleus'] 
ran = 'image1.png'
```

The output is an empty data frame when I instead want;

```
image1.png, 1023, 554, 1126, 646, nucleus
image1.png, 1023, 554, 116, 646, nucleus
image1.png, 103, 544, 1126, 6, nucleus
image1.png, 10, 354, 1556, 56, nucleus
image1.png, 13, 55, 1216, 46, nucleus
image1.png, 103, 54, 116, 326, nucleus
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are you trying to copy one dataframe to another?

Comment: I am trying to copy specific lines from one data frame to another

Comment: append , concat

Comment: Append not concat

Comment: And what is ran?

Comment: Or just say what is the original dataframe structure and what is the condition

Comment: ran is a random line from the original data frame. I will add this to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your code by changing:

```
 empty_df.append(new)
```

to:

```
 empty_df = empty_df.append(new)
```

but I don't think you should do that. You'd have a much easier time copying the whole dataframe with

```
 empty_df = data.copy()
```

Comment: It should get the job Done for the OP, but it wouldn't be most efficient, as in this method also to get the condition he is iterating linearly which will be a time kill.

Comment: P.S. Iterating is a very slow way to solve your problem. It's very inefficient and there is probably a better way.

Comment: LOL. I just posted basically the same comment. I agree. We just don't know enough about the OPs problem to give a more elegant solution. @anand_v.singh, you are the hero Gotham needs.

Comment: This method prints out the data in a single column as opposed to across the six rows. Example,
1 image1.png
2 1023
3 554
4 1126
5 646
6 nucleus

Comment: Yes exactly the information kinda limits the scope of the answer :)

Comment: @p.strain Put the condition you want to use in your question directly, also mention column labels

Answer (score 0):

I believe all what you are doing can be simplified by filter a new DF based on `ran`

```
empty_df = data[data.iloc[:,0] == ran]
empty_df.head()
Output:
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   image1.png  1023    554 1126    646 nucleus
1   image1.png  1023    554 116 646 nucleus
2   image1.png  103 544 1126    6   nucleus
3   image1.png  10  354 1556    56  nucleus
4   image1.png  13  55  1216    46  nucleus
```

Comment: O.P. mentioned ran to be a variable and not a list.

Comment: @anand_v.singh thank you for the warning. I have adapted my answer

Answer (score 0):

To change the column use
suppose the name of the column in which Image name is stored is `imageName` and ran is the variable.

```
new_df = data.loc[data['imageName'] == ran ] #if ran is a variable
```